# MYSQL & PHP limit with offset syntax error

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo

I have a filtering features for products:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1 ';
$data = [];
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $query .= "AND name LIKE :name ";
    $data[':name'] = '%' . $name . '%';
}
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
    $query .= "LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset ";
    $data[':offset'] = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * 10;
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1 AND name LIKE :name LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset
```

I get the following error:

> uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0'' at line 1

I tried to separate `:offset` with `bindParam`:

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
    $query .= "LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset ";
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
if($_GET['page']){
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
$stmt->execute($data);
```

I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Your question (still) isn't consistent. You start with code containing `AND name LIKE :name` yet your query supposedly contains: `AND name LIKE :customer`. Please try to give us an code example that you know produces the error you get. Test it yourself before you publish it here.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Updated with the correct data.

Comment: Well, you edited the question by changing `:customer` to `:name`, but where did that `:customer` come from? How do we know that the code, that is currently in your question, does actually produce the error you report?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `:name` and `:customer` is not the problem. It's related to the offset

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: Where is the `'0'` coming from?

Comment: You never set the variable `$offset`.

Comment: @SalmanA from the offset as it was 0

Comment: @Barmar from this `($_GET['page'] - 1) * 10;`

Comment: Please edit the question to show your current code, there's too much missing.

Comment: @Barmar The whole code is over there. People look at tiny things and the issue is obvious it's related to this part `$query .= "LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset ";` the `:offset` could be any number and in my case, it's 0 and if I change it to 1 it would be the same.

Comment: Using `:bindParam` with `PDO::PARAM_INT` should have solved the problem.

Comment: @Barmar Then, I would have to use the same conditions again before every `bindParam`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I was talking about the `bindParam` in the `if`, I think it should work. But you should use `if (isset($_GET['page']))`

Comment: @Barmar If I use `bindParam` then I have to do the same for all request data like `name`. So I would have to write every condition 2 times `if (isset($_GET['page']))` to append to the query and `if (isset($_GET['page']))` to `bindParam`. The same for `if (isset($_GET['name'])`

Comment: You can mix `bindParam()` with passing an array to `execute()`. The parameters are combined.

Comment: @Barmar I tried that and got the error at the end of my question.

Comment: That's why I wanted to see the whole code, that shouldn't happen. So we need to see how you're setting `$data`.

Comment: @Barmar It contains one item if I mix both `$data` and `bindParam` `$data[':name'] = '%' . $name . '%';`

Comment: Why won't you just edit the question and show the code? We need to see both the query and the data.

Comment: Hmm, I think I was wrong. I just tried a test and it didn't work to mix them. I could have sworn this worked.

Comment: Use `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` and then you'll be able to use the original `data[':offset']` code. See the new duplicate I added.